# Tkinter Label Widget weird behavior when changing color and text via List of Variables

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm building a little Accountant tool so I stop spending money on useless stuff.

Since I am working with big Lists of Invoices I wanted to structure and color them by Categories, because I need to know where to cut Spending in general.

Since Listboxes don't support Multiline Text and no colors I wanted to use Buttons which dynamically change when scrolling.

I discovered that Buttons don't support fonts which makes working with long IBAN Strings very shitty.

Then I decided to use Label widgets which provide Coloring, Font and Multiline and created my own Widget.

This is the function which gets called when the user is scrolling and the Labels have to change Color and Text:

```
def Refresh (self):

    for button in self.buttons:
        
        try:

            index = self.buttons.index(button) + self.ListIndex


            if type(self.textList[index]) is list:

    
                button.configure(text = self.textList[index][0] , bg = self.textList[index][1])
                

            else:

                button.config(text = self.textList[index])

        except IndexError:
                button.config(text = " ",bg = "#d9d9d9")
```

Variable Samples:

```
self.buttons = A list of Label references created when the Widget gets called length depends on how many buttons the user wants being displayed

self.ListIndex = Basically an Index offset, which gets in/decremented when the user is scrolling up or down

self.textList = list of config data for the Labels which elements maybe string or list
self.textList = [['foo', '#eb3434'],'bar']

index = 0
self.textList[index][0] = Invoice Details to be displayed
self.textList[index][1] = Invoice Group Color for easy recognition
```

now with only the text config:

```
button.configure(text = self.textList[index][0])
```

Expected Result:

[image]

Now this is very weird when I try to config the color with:

```
button.configure(text = self.textList[index][0] , bg = self.textList[index][1])
```

Not expected Result:

[image]

After Scrolling:

[image]

After a little bit of semantic debug I found out that the colors are in the correct position. Where text and color appears, to be random.

Comment: When a `textList` entry is only a string (instead of a 2-element list), you still need to configure both the text and the color (presumably to some default color), as otherwise that label will retain whatever color it had before scrolling.  If that's not the whole problem, we really need to see a [mcve] to be able to help.

Comment: What do you mean by _"I discovered that Buttons dont support fonts "_? You can definitely change the font used by a button.

Comment: "Since Listboxes don't support Multiline Text and no colors": Listboxes do support colors, you can set the color of a given line with `listbox.itemconfigure(<index>, background=<color>, foreground=<color>)`